# No property 'findAll' found for type 'Department'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am facing an issue after migrating from spring-boot 1.5.3-release to 2.7.16, the error is DepartmentRepository.findAll(java.lang.Iterable)! No property 'findAll' found for type 'Department'

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.auth.middleware.domain.Department;

@Repository

public interface DepartmentRepository extends CrudRepository<Department, Long> {

@Transactional(timeout = 8)
List<Department> findAll();
 

/**
 * 
 * @param deptId
 * @return
 */
Department findByDeptId(Long deptId);

/**
 * @param deptName
 * @return
 */
Department findByDeptName(String deptName);

/**
 * 
 * @param deptId
 */
void deleteByDeptId(Long deptId);


/**
 * @param deptIds
 */
@Transactional(timeout = 8)
Iterable<Department> findAll(Iterable<Long> deptIds);



}
```

The error is coming while starting the application
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.Iterable com.auth.middleware.repository.DepartmentRepository.findAll(java.lang.Iterable);
It was working before in spring-boot 1.5.3-release, after upgrading to 2.7.16 I am facing this issue.

Comment: Not clear... The error means that you are looking for `Department.findAll(..)`, but the code shows that the method is in `DepartmentRepository` class.

Comment: The error is coming while starting the application.....  Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.Iterable com.auth.middleware.repository.DepartmentRepository.findAll(java.lang.Iterable);

Comment: Is it possible to edit the `DepartmentRepository` class? Also, using `findAll( Iterable )`, are you trying to get rows for the passed department ids? If yes, then please try renaming the method to `findByDeptIdIn( Iterable )` (use the right field property name and path).

Comment: Ok thanks, It is in a jar file, but let me edit and  it and test.

Comment: That issue is resolve. Thanks. Your suggestion worked

Comment: Great. I will add this as the answer. Can you please accept it?

Comment: sure, i will accept,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is it possible to edit the `DepartmentRepository class`?
- Also, using `findAll( Iterable )`, are you trying to get rows for the passed department ids?

If answers to both is "yes", then please try renaming the method to `findByDeptIdIn( Iterable )`. (Since the `Department` class is not available here, please ensure that you use the right field property name and path, including the key property's name, if applicable).